# object 'trend' not found

Tags: r, forecast

When I run my model with a polynomial trend with `tslm`, I get the following error:

> Error in structure(x, class = unique(c("AsIs", oldClass(x)))) : object
>   'trend' not found

Here is my R code:

```
mymodel <- tslm(activations ~ trend*season + I(trend^2) + I(sqrt(sold)) + I(sqrt(sold1)) + I(sqrt(sold2)), my_df_ts_all) #final model
my_fc <- forecast(mymodel, h = 12, newdata = tvs_data_test[1:12, ])
my_fc
```

If I remove I(trend^2), it runs okay. Any ideas?

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducible example and the packages you used

Comment: sounds like the variable `trend` doesn't exist. if you type `my_df_ts_all$trend` into your console, does it show anything? make sure you haven't called it `Trend` or anything as R is case-sensitive